# Layout problems, cannot interact with map

Tags: android, android-layout

I need some help with a layout. I have a map, a drawer, a button for the drawer and a cardview to hold the autocomplete search box. Everything looks fine except i cannot interact with the map. Pinch zoom, swipe to move and My Location button are not working. I think it's because the layout is wrong and i'm not actually interacting with the map but with something else. Posting my layout below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
map:uiZoomControls="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
map:mapType="normal"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MapsActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/LeftDrawer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="Test Title" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TitleTextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="Test Title 2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/test_button1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|start"
                android:background="@drawable/settings"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/test_button2"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|start"
                android:background="@drawable/settings"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drawer_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:onClick="OpenCloseDrawer"
        android:background="@drawable/settings"/>

</fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Posting a screenshot of what the app looks like. Top left button is the open/close drawer button. As seen in the screen shot,[image] that button (@+id/drawer_button) becomes inaccessable. The drawer closes when touching outside, but i have code in that button that then never fires as the button is not accessable. So i would like to always have access to the button, as well as probably some way of detecting the drawer closing, so i can use the same code in that event as i do in my button in case the user just swipes/touches outside to close the drawer.

Here are my layouts as the are now.

activity_maps.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/map" layout="@layout/fragment" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/whatYouWantInLeftDrawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Title1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleTextView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Ttitle2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_button1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@drawable/settings"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_button2"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@drawable/settings"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
map:uiZoomControls="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
map:mapType="normal"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MapsActivity">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drawer_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:onClick="OpenCloseDrawer"
        android:background="@drawable/settings"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </fragment>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the device for this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to understand is that your will have only two child like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        < first View, here you will have your google map/>

        < second View, here you will have your ListView/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

now the problem is that you don't just have a plain google map to show as First View, what you can do is create a separate fragment which will replace your first view,

There are many ways to do this depending on what you want to achieve with it, it will work fine as long as you keep this pattern for `DrawerLayout`

well to make it simple create fragment which will have `google map` and your `cardview`

fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout>
       <GoogleMapFragment
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

       <CardView
           android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

now make some changes to your Navigation drawer layout like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <first View, include fragment & class representing that stuff/>

        < second View, here you will have your ListView/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is just an example that you make implement your own layout:

> Update

```
<FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <first View, include fragment & class representing that stuff/>

            < second View, here you will have your ListView
              margin="leave enough margin to top as you will have buttons, otherwise button will overlap listview"
              />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <LinearLayout>

        <put your button Views here, so these will appear all the time/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it working now except my open/close drawer button. Don't know where in the layouts i should put that to keep it "enabled" at all times. I have some code tied to this button and it does not fire as the button is not "enabled" once the drawer layout is "on top" so to speak. Also, now the drawer is closed once i touch outside it, like on the map, which is kinda nice, but i need to catch that close event in order to process the selections made in the listview. Any suggestions on where to do that?

Comment: if you are using an **toolbar** or **actionbar** you can put your button there, if that is not the case with your layout i will make you something

Comment: I'm not using any toolbar/actionbar so if you have any suggestions that would be awesome. Thanks in advance! Edit: will post my current layout when i get home in a few hours.

Comment: @Maverick, give me some time i will update my answer :)

Comment: @Maverick, i was thinking about what you want to make and bit confused, if it possible for you to give me some rough image about how exactly do you want it to look like, i will make it that way

Comment: Hi again! I updated my original post with a screenshot and some info that hopefully makes sense. =)

Comment: Thanks, but no matter what i do the button always gets inaccessable =/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99919/discussion-between-pankaj-nimgade-and-maverick).

Comment: @Maverick, Kindly mail me the layout i will check that to make any correction needed. 
pankaj.nimgade@gmail.com

Comment: Awesome mate, i've sent you an email.